# How do I configure apt-get to use a Pac file for a proxy?

Tags: apt, proxy

In my workplace we use the Pac file for proxy network .And the Pac file when i give to the browser setting its work fine Edit-->Advance-->Network-->Setting. When i gave the Url its working fine for me.

But for apt-get i was not able to update.

I added the same URL in the network proxy for that. My pac file have no username or password.

Please suggest me .How should the apt-get work in my new ubuntu 11.10.I am really struggling a lot to fix this issue

Answer (score 8):

I do not know if APT is able to use a PAC file directly but you can (with quite a bit of work/understanding) extract the relevant proxy information from the PAC file itself and use this information to configure APT to use a HTTP proxy.

The PAC file essentially consists of a JavaScript function. The **return** statement (one or more) of the function returns the proxy server address and port, for example:

```
return "PROXY proxy.some.site:8080; DIRECT";
```

Just look at your PAC file by entering its address in a browser. With this information you can create an APT configuration file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy
```

You should modify the file so that it contains the following information:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxy.some.site:8080";
```

Save the file and the next **apt-get** run should use the configured proxy setting.

*It would be nice if APT could work with PAC files because we also use them in our company. Perhaps somebody else knows if/how it works...*

The [Ubuntu Wiki Page for AptGet](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy) also has some hints how to configure a proxy for APT.

See also https://superuser.com/questions/323488/ubuntu-system-wide-proxy-auto-configuration-pac-script

Comment: FWIW - I had issues getting apt to work behind our MS ISA proxy. I'd tried the bash.rc method; didn't work. But creating the /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/proxy file and adding an entry in the format Acquire::http::Proxy "http://domain\username:password@proxy_name:8080"; did the trick.

Comment: In my case, `sudo gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf` and add the line above works.